# Firebase `signInWithCredential` put empty emails

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm pulling my hair out on this, I don't know the logic behind but most of the users who uses the facebook login through my app has an empty email. When I check the Authentication tab for users, their supposedly email is just `—`. The integration is actually working, some users have proper email set but some are not.

I'm passing the `accessToken` I got from facebook through `signInWithCredential` method. This is written in javascript btw.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(accessToken))
```

I'm pretty sure firebase do the rest to take out emails from the `accessToken`. So this means some users don't really have an email set? Is that even possible? Does firebase still authenticate existing users with such case?

If anybody could shed some light to this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you checking the email in firebase.auth().currentUser.providerData[0].email? Also make sure you don't have multiple accounts per email enabled in the Firebase Console.

Answer (score 0):

If you making chrome app or extension, make sure you add this to the manifest file:

```
"scopes": [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
]
```